# Cech homology groups

Tags: homology-cohomology

Let X and Y two compact Hausdorff spaces. If f is a homeomorphism of X into Y, then for each covering $\mathfrak{U}$ in $\Sigma(X)$, the collection $f(\mathfrak{U})$ of all images of elements of $\mathfrak{U}$  is an open covering of Y and conversely.

How can I prove that the Cech homology groups $H_{p}(X, G)$ and $H_{p}(Y, G)$ are isomorphic?

Thank you

Comment: *Do not vandalize the question.*

Comment: @PeterTamaroff read the edit history, what happened?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $H_p(-,G):Top\to Ab$ is a functor.

Recall that homeomorphisms are isomorphisms in $Top$.

Finally prove (it is immediate) that any functor maps isomorphisms to isomorphisms.

Comment: Is there another way to prove it without using homotopy?

Comment: Where hadI used homotopy?